# how drivers work (e.g. PCIe and USB)

Tags: operating-system, driver

I am curious about how drivers in general work. I do understand basic concepts and also how a single driver operates. Where I am confused is how they work when multiple drivers are involved.

Let me explain my question through an example:

Suppose I have a PCIe and USB interface in HW. The primary interface to host (where driver, OS, applications reside) is PCIe. USB interface is accessible to host through PCIe.

So, in this case, I would have driver for PCIe as well for USB.
When data has to be transferred through USB by application, application would invoke system/OS calls. This would eventually land up in USB driver.
Is this correct?

Once USB driver has completed processing, PCIe calls have to be called. Who does it? is it OS or USB driver itself?
I would assume that, it would be OS as otherwise it would break basic modular philosophy. But driver calling OS seems counterintuitive as I always assumed flow to be from application to OS to driver and HW.

Can anyone please throw some light on this topic?

Comment: Google 'interrupts'

Comment: Unfortunately, this is highly system specific.

Answer (score 3):

Much like in user space code, there exist standardized APIs for access various types of hardware in kernel land(exact usage varies by OS). As a result it isn't really that much of a stretch for one device driver to access another device's driver via these standardized APIs. (Warning: USB is a very complex protocol, and many details have been glossed over to keep a long post shorter)

The original question focused on PCIe to USB cards. In this example I think it's helpful to think of there being three "layers" of drivers. The first layer is the PCIe bus controller driver, which controls PCIe bus specific functions such as mapping out MMIO for PCIe devices and supporting interrupts from those PCIe devices. The second layer is the USB host controller layer, which provides the functions for issuing standardized USB transactions. Finally, the USB device driver (like a USB driver keyboard) sits on top of the stack using the standardized USB transaction to implement the functionality of the specific USB peripheral device. Calls from the keyboard driver will call functions down in the USB host controller driver, which in turn may even call down to the PCIe driver. All of this is done in the kernel space, even though many separate drivers are employed.

Most PCIe devices do the bulk of their communication with the CPU via MMIO access, which appear as memory reads/writes to the processor. Generally no specific driver function is needed to perform the MMIO transfer of data from PCIe to CPU (although there may be some simple access functions to do endian correction or deal with cache issues).

USB host controller drivers are interesting in that they conform to a standard (such as XHCI, the USB 3.0 standard, which I'll use in this example) which dictates a standard device memory map and behavior. Thus there usually is some chip specific driver performs non-standard initialization to the USB host controller device. Additionally, these chip specific drivers will both retrieve the location of the XHCI standardized MMIO region and provide a way to receive interrupts from the XHCI controller (in this example from PCIe interrupts).

Next, this standardized memory region and interrupt mechanism is passed to a generic XHCI host controller driver. The generic XHCI code does not care if the device is PCIe, it just cares that it gets passed a memory region that follows the XHCI standard and that it receives the correct interrupts  The XHCI driver provides the generic USB transfer functions which in turn the USB keyboard device can use to initiate USB transactions.

For the most part, the XHCI driver is just going to do read/writes to the  MMIO region that was passed in. This allows the same common XHCI code to service a wide array USB host controllers, many of which are not PCIe devices. Thus effectively allowing the XHCI driver to abstract away the underlying hardware implementing the USB controller. Thus, for the example posed by the original question, the USB host controller standards are designed to hide the underlying hardware mechanisms to make for a more modular USB driver system.